# Two OR statements MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT b_id,b_thumb1,b_thumb2,b_league,b_date,b_status 
FROM battles 
WHERE b_userid1=? OR b_userid2=? 
AND b_status=1 OR b_status=2 
ORDER BY b_date DESC
```

This is selecting rows where `b_status = 0` rather than just `1` or `2`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: if the question mark should be a zero that means, `b_userid1 = 0` or `b_userid2=0 AND b_status=1` or `b_status=2 `. If you want a right output care for the [prescedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Comment: WHERE (b_userid1=? OR b_userid2=?) 
AND (b_status=1 OR b_status=2) ?

Comment: @jarlh that worked, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should add `()` to `where` statement.

```
SELECT b_id,b_thumb1,b_thumb2,b_league,b_date,b_status 
FROM battles 
WHERE (b_userid1=? OR b_userid2=?) 
AND (b_status=1 OR b_status=2) 
ORDER BY b_date DESC
```

A little advice on your `SQL`, use `IN` statement to replace multiple `OR` statement.

```
SELECT b_id,b_thumb1,b_thumb2,b_league,b_date,b_status 
FROM battles 
WHERE (b_userid1 in (?, ?)) 
AND (b_status in (1, 2)) 
ORDER BY b_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b_id,b_thumb2,b_league,b_date,b_status 
FROM battles 
WHERE (b_userid1=? OR b_userid2=?) 
AND (b_status=1 OR b_status=2) 
ORDER BY b_date DESC
```

This will give you a result where b_userid is equal to one of the two parameters, and the status is 1 or 2.

```
SELECT b_id,b_thumb2,b_league,b_date,b_status 
FROM battles 
WHERE b_userid1=? OR b_userid2=?
AND b_status=1 OR b_status=2 
ORDER BY b_date DESC
```

This will return results where the b_userid1 is equal to the first parameter or b_userid2 is equal to the second parameter and status = 1 or b_status = 2 (probably, the order of operations on sql is sort of hard).

So it is equal to this:

```
SELECT b_id,b_thumb2,b_league,b_date,b_status 
FROM battles 
WHERE (b_userid1=?) OR (b_userid2=? 
AND b_status=1) OR (b_status=2) 
ORDER BY b_date DESC
```

which isn't quite what you want.